# Filtering identityRiskEvents by date

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to filter `/identityRiskEvents` by date using Microsoft Graph?

I've been using the `$filter` operator on the `createdDateTime` field as I'd like to pull that last X amount of days, but every time I run the PS script, I only get the first events from a few months back.

Comment: Removing `microsoft-graph` tag.  The Risky Sign-ins Report isn't available from Microsoft Graph, it is only available in Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: According to Microsoft's website it is - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-identityprotection-graph-getting-started:
"Microsoft Graph is the Microsoft unified API endpoint and the home of Azure Active Directory Identity Protection APIs. The first API, identityRiskEvents, allows you to query Microsoft Graph for a list of risk events and associated information. This article gets you started querying this API. For an in-depth introduction, full documentation, and access to the Graph Explorer, see the Microsoft Graph site."

Comment: Yes but `identityRiskEvents` is not the `Risky Sign-ins Report`. That report is only available via Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: Marc, apologize as I wasn't clear in my original post as I should've stated how to filter on Azure AD Identity Protection - Risk events via Microsoft Graph. The identityRiskEvents covers the six types of risk events Azure AD Identity Protection - Risk events.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

No, The Risky Sign-in is not available through Microsoft Graph. You can use “[signinDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-sign-in-activity-reference#signindatetime)” filter with Azure AD Graph API which defines a date or date range.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the previous answer from Ajay got me moving in the right direction.

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?&`$filter=createdDateTime gt $date1"
```

Be sure to include the grave accent (backtick) in the URL before the $.  See these documents for more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/graph-get-started
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/signin_list
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters